# lwIP mqtt connection error on stm32f4 discovery

Tags: mqtt, stm32, mosquitto, lwip

I am trying to use lwIP for a client, which sends data to mosquitto broker on stm32f407 discovery.

Mqtt application is implemented at lwIP. I just use them like that at main after initializing. 
`mqtt_client_t static_client;`

Afterwards, with USART interrupt, I call
`example_do_connect(&static_client); example_publish(&static_client,0);`

Which calls those functions:

```
{
  struct mqtt_connect_client_info_t ci;
  err_t err;

  /* Setup an empty client info structure */
  memset(&ci, 0, sizeof(ci));

  /* Minimal amount of information required is client identifier, so set it here */
  ci.client_id = "lwip_test";
    ci.client_user = NULL;
    ci.client_pass = NULL;

  /* Initiate client and connect to server, if this fails immediately an error code is returned
     otherwise mqtt_connection_cb will be called with connection result after attempting
     to establish a connection with the server.
     For now MQTT version 3.1.1 is always used */

  err = mqtt_client_connect(client, &serverIp, MQTT_PORT, mqtt_connection_cb, 0, &ci);

  /* For now just print the result code if something goes wrong*/
  if(err != ERR_OK) {

  }
}
```

and

```
void example_publish(mqtt_client_t *client, void *arg)
{
  const char *pub_payload= "stm32_test";
  err_t err;
  u8_t qos = 2; /* 0 1 or 2, see MQTT specification */
  u8_t retain = 0; /* No don't retain such crappy payload... */
  err = mqtt_publish(client, "pub_topic", pub_payload, strlen(pub_payload), qos, retain, mqtt_pub_request_cb, arg);
  if(err != ERR_OK) {
  //  printf("Publish err: %d\n", err);
    err = ERR_OK;
  }
}

/* Called when publish is complete either with sucess or failure */
static void mqtt_pub_request_cb(void *arg, err_t result)
{
  if(result != ERR_OK) {
  //  printf("Publish result: %d\n", result);
  }
}
```

I am able to ping board, my IP adress has been assigned in main by using `IP_ADDR4(&serverIp, 192,168,2,97);`

I've used all needed functions like MX_LWIP_Init(), MX_LWIP_Process() and actually i am even able to implement a TCP client, which is working nice. So internet connection is well, but I guess, there is a point that i missed in mqttclient. Callbacks is also have done by Erik Anderssen's guide.

When i try to subscribe to board's IP by using mosquitto, Error: no connection could be made because the target actively refused it. If you notice some point that i have missed or have an idea, please let me know.

Any help will appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that the server refused the connection when QoS (quality of service) was set to 2, but the server needed it to be 0. Try changing the parameter qos in the line in the connection callback to either 0 or 1:

`err = mqtt_subscribe(mqtt.client, "topic", qos, MqttApp_SubscribeRequestCallback, arg);`

Same applies to the parameter qos in the publish function:

change `u8_t qos = 2;` to `u8_t qos = 0;` (or 1 - whatever your server requires)

Hope it helps. Cheers.